# How to access a variable's value in public class c++

Tags: c++

I have three different classes: Student, Course, and Enrollment. Each classes will have same functions to add a new student, course, or enrollment. In my main, I have created three dynamic objects array with the size depends on the user (my object array will increase by 1 each time a new element in the array is added). I have successfully added value for each new element in the array, and print it normally. However, If i need to access the variable's value from one class in another class, then I would get 0. 
For example,

My student class will look like this:

```
class Student {
    studentID;
    studentName;
    Student *AddStudent(getting value for object in class Student);
}
```

My Course class:

```
class Course {
    courseID;
    courseName;
    Course *addCourse(getting value for object in class Course)
}
```

My Enrollment class:

```
class Enrollment {
    Student getStudentID[totalStudent];//Here I declare an empty object of class Student, that means by default, my studentID value in arrays is 0.
    Course getCourseID[totalCourse];//Same for here
    void AddEnrollment(Enrollment *newEnrollment, int totalCourse, int numStudent, int &countEnrollment, int &totalEnrollment) {
        // I can user Student *newStudent, and Course *newCourse
        // as a paramater because it is not declare in my Enrollment.h
        // Checking student ID and course ID to see if these ID exists
        // in either class or not, if not, then the user have to enter
        // a valid ID before enrolling.Enrollment tempEnrollment;
        Student tempStudent[numStudent]; //I declare an empty array so by default constructor, studentID is 0
        Course tempCourse[totalCourse];//Same for this one
        int studentID, courseID;
        bool checkStuID = false;
        bool checkCourID = false;

        cout << "Enter a student ID: ";
        cin >> tempEnrollment.student_ID;
        while (checkStuID == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; i++)
            {
                cout << tempStudent[i].getID() << " ";
                if (tempEnrollment.student_ID == tempStudent[i].getID())
                {
                checkStuID = true;
                }
            }
            if (checkStuID == false)
            {
                cout << "This student ID is not in the system. Please enter a valid student ID. \n";
                cin >> tempEnrollment.student_ID;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My Enrollment header:

```
class Enrollment{
public:
    int course_ID;
    int student_ID;
    int enrollment_ID;
    int student_Grade[10];
    int countGrade;
    int averageGrade;
    char letterGrade;
    Enrollment();


//If I try to pass array as reference such as Student *s, Course *c or Student s[], Course c[], I would get an error as class Student and Course is not declared in this Enrollment class so access them is impossible
        void AddEnrollment(Enrollment* &newEnrollment, int totalCourse, int numStudent, int &countEnrollment, int &totalEnrollment);
        void AddGrade(Enrollment *newGrade, int totalEnrollment);
        Enrollment* IncreasingSize(Enrollment *newEnrollment, int oldSize, int newSize);
};
```

My Main class:

```
int main() {
    Student *newStudent = new Student[countStudent];
    Course *newCourse = new Course[countCourse];
    Enrollment *newEnrollment = new Enrollment[countEnrollment];

    newStudent->AddStudent();
    newCourse->AddCourse();
    newEnrollment->AddEnrollment(...);
}
```

My problem here is that I cant get the studentID and the course ID to check if it match with the ID inputed from the user. It will always get me '0' or random number since there is no data in the object's array I create in the Enrollment class. So is there any way I can do to get these value? I have tried using include "Student.h" or "Course.h" in the Enrollment.h header file, but it would give me an error like the redefinition of class Student or Course.

For example:

```
My student ID is: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

My Course ID is: 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10

ID the user input for studentID and courseID is: 1 - 6
The ID I will get in Enrollment class is either '0' or '251235' (random number)
```

What I think to solve this problem is using a pointer of Student and Course class as a parameter to access the array's variable value such as `addEnrollment(Enrollment *newEnrollment, Student *newStudent, Course *newCourse)`, but it will give me an error since my function's prototype in header does not contain the Student or Course declaration.

Comment: It's difficult to provide helpful suggestions with bits and pieces of code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If you don't specify access modifiers (e.g. `public:`) then all your code is per default private.

Comment: Would love it if you could post some complete code segments. Are these inherited classes or are they all in one file?

Comment: You seem to be compaining about multiple problems. Compiler errors in some cicrumstances and runtime error in others, It's very hard to help. Could you please narrow down your problem to one specific question. And since some of your problems concern how your code is organised, could you please make it clear what the file names are, and what files include what other files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you use composition in this case 
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/.

```
addEnrollment(Enrollment *newEnrollment, Student *newStudent, Course *newCourse)
```

This is the right way to do it with little modifications as below.

```
addEnrollment(Student *newStudent, Course *newCourse){
// here you try to create the new enrollment object and push it in your data structure.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding after reading your question is that you aren't able to get value's from classes?

The reason is `class` is private by default, so you would need to create a getter and setter if you need to retrieve or change the values.

Comment: I did declare public: with all my variables.

Comment: I have added some complete code above. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hope that member attributes are declared as Public in your actual code
2. Student *newStudent = new Student[countStudent];
   Course *newCourse = new Course[countCourse];

newStudent and newCourse point to an array of "Student" class and not to one specific student.
Do you want it work this way? Inside AddEnrollment method, are you pointing to the right object instance?
Please paste the complete code for better investigation.

```
//declaration
void addEnrollment(Student s[], Course c[]);
Student *newStudent = new Student[countStudent];
Course *newCourse = new Course[countCourse];

addEnrollment(newStudent, newCourse);

addEnrollment(Student s[], Course c[]) {
    for(i=0; i<countStudent;i++)
    cout << s[i].studentID;
}
```

Note: You can pass reference too

Comment: I declare all my variables with public in all classes. That is exactly how I want my two array's object work. At first, I will create an object pointer to an array with size [1], then every time a new element in that array is added, then my array's size will increase to 2 and so on. I know that I did wrong in my AddEnrollment function because It will just create an array of object with size of [totalStudent or totalCourse] with empty value for all variables in the class. I want to know how to pass the newStudent and newCourse into my addEnrollment function as a parameter.

Comment: //declaration
void addEnrollment(Student s[], Course c[]);                       

Student *newStudent = new Student[countStudent];
Course *newCourse = new Course[countCourse];

addEnrollment(newStudent, newCourse);

addEnrollment(Student s[], Course c[])
{
 for(i=0; i<countStudent;i++)
  cout << s[i].studentID;

}                                                                                                                            You can pass reference to this array of pointer too...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at and run this minimal example and let us know if it's something like what you are trying to achieve.

```
#include <iostream>
class Course {
public:
    int ID;
    Course(int id) : ID(id) {};
};

class Student {
public:
    Student(int id) : ID(id) { noOfCourses = 0; }
    void addCourse(Course c) {
        courses[noOfCourses] = c.ID;
        noOfCourses++;
    }
    int ID;
    int *courses;
    int noOfCourses;
};

class Enrolment {
public:
    static bool checkEnrolment(Student my) {
        bool checkStuID = false;
        int courseID = 0;
        while (!checkStuID) {
            std::cout << "check a course: " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> courseID;
            // iterate through students courses comparing with input course.
            for (int i = 0; i < my.noOfCourses; i++)
            {
                if (my.courses[i] == courseID)
                {
                    checkStuID = true;
                    std::cout << my.ID << " is enrolled in " 
                              << courseID << "." << std::endl;
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            std::cout << my.ID << " is not enrolled in " 
                      << courseID << "." << std::endl;
            courseID = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Student johnny(1234);
    Course math(123);
    Course science(456);
    johnny.addCourse(math);
    johnny.addCourse(science);
    Enrolment::checkEnrolment(johnny);
}
```